# Weighted conditions in the WHERE clause of a SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I want to search for records where a particular field either STARTS WITH some string (let's say "ar") OR that field CONTAINS the string, "ar".

However, I consider the two conditions different, because I'm limiting the number of results returned to 10 and I want the STARTS WITH condition to be weighted more heavily than the CONTAINS condition.

Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees
WHERE Name LIKE 'ar%' OR Name LIKE '%ar%'
LIMIT 10
```

The catch is that is that if there are names that START with "ar" they should be favored.  The only way I should get back a name that merely CONTAINS "ar" is if there are LESS than 10 names that START with "ar"

How can I do this against a MySQL database?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to select them in 2 parts, and add a Preference tag to the results.  10 from each segment, then merge them and take again the best 10.  If segment 1 produces 8 entries, then segment 2 of UNION ALL will product the remaining 2

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT *, 1 as Preferred
FROM Employees
WHERE Name LIKE 'ar%'
LIMIT 10
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, 2
    FROM Employees
    WHERE Name NOT LIKE 'ar%' AND Name LIKE '%ar%'
    LIMIT 10
) X
) Y
ORDER BY Preferred
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This seems to work for me.  Can you explain it at all?  I understand (generally speaking) what union means.  What are the X and Y and what is the ,1 and ,2?

Comment: @Stephen - X and Y are just aliases given to subqueries (each derived table must be aliased - so that they can be referenced if required). You can add a column to any result set, by just giving a value and naming (aliasing) the column. In this case, I added a column named "Preferred" with a value of 1 in the first part, and a value of 2 in the 2nd part. The columns is now part of the result (for the query out).

Comment: Great! That worked for me.  Now what if I wanted a random order in the subqueries.  In other words,  sorted by groups 1 and 2, but random order within each group.  I tried adding ORDER BY RAND() to each of the subqueries and I got an error: General error: 1221 Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY'  Can those not be used together at all?

Comment: @JoshuaGoossen use "ORDER BY Preferred, Rand()" at the very end

Answer (score 4):

Assign a code value to results, and sort by the code value:

```
select
    *,
    (case when name like 'ar%' then 1 else 2 end) as priority
from
    employees
where
    name like 'ar%' or name like '%ar%'
order by
    priority
limit 10
```

**Edit:**

See Richard aka cyberkiwi's answer for a more efficient solution if there are potentially lots of matches.

Comment: If the table contains many matches, then this can be slower since it has to first assign a priority to all matches.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees
WHERE Name LIKE '%ar%'
ORDER BY instr(name, 'ar'), name
LIMIT 10
```

The *instr()* looks for the first occurrence of the pattern in question.  AR% will come before xxAR.

This prevents:

1. Should only do table scan 1 time. Unions and derived tables do 3. The first two on the columns to filter out the patterns and then the 3rd on the subset to find where they equal - since union filters out dupes.
2. Gives a true sort based on the location of the pattern. Wx > xW > xxW > etc...

Comment: This indeed is a killer solution! Concise and efficient!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (don't have a MySQL instance immediately available to test with):

```
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Name LIKE 'ar%'
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Name LIKE '%ar%'
   )
 LIMIT 10
```

There are probably better ways to do it, but that immediately sprang to mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees
WHERE Name LIKE 'ar%' OR Name LIKE '%ar%'
ORDER BY LIKE 'ar%' DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Should work orders by the binary true / false for like and if index'ed should benefit from the index